# How do I replace a deprecated null-loader regex test with webpack 5's resolve.alias?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am looking at a package that currently uses a `null-loader` call in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      /* Use null-loader to drop resources that are not used ... */
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: 'null-loader'
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

`null-loader` is now deprecated, and has been replaced by `resolve.alias` in webpack 5.  But how can I convert this regex test into an appropriate `resolve.alias` clause?  Looking at the `resolve.alias` documentation at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias, the most "obvious" thing to write would be:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/: false,
    },
  },
};
```

but that is not valid syntax (and removing the slashes does not help either).

Is there an equivalent webpack clause for the `null-loader` test?

Comment: I think I may have solved it; replace the regex line with: `"\\.(jpg|png|gif)$": false,`, making the regex a string instead.  I'm not certain this works correctly, so would still be happy to hear comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) only says it supports `string` as its property, not regex.

> [string] values are supported since webpack 5.

For safety, we'd better use string as its properties. We can use [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) package to match files using patterns and then set them to `false` to ignore.

E.g.

Directory structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 -I 'node_modules|dist'
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── a.jpg
│   ├── b.png
│   ├── c.gif
│   └── index.js
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
console.log('webpack mini template');

console.log(require('./a.jpg'));
console.log(require('./b.png'));
console.log(require('./c.gif'));
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const glob = require('glob');

const ignoreAssets = glob.globSync('src/*.{png,jpg,gif}', { absolute: true });

const ignoreModules = ignoreAssets.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] = false;
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log('ignoreModules: ', ignoreModules);

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        clean: true,
        publicPath: '',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ...ignoreModules,
        },
    },
};
```

Build logs:

```
$ npm run build

> @1.0.0 build /home/lindu/workspace/webpack-samples/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/76700259
> webpack

ignoreModules:  {
  '/home/lindu/workspace/webpack-samples/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/76700259/src/c.gif': false,
  '/home/lindu/workspace/webpack-samples/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/76700259/src/b.png': false,
  '/home/lindu/workspace/webpack-samples/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/76700259/src/a.jpg': false
}
asset main.js 2.97 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
./src/index.js 138 bytes [built] [code generated]
./a.jpg (ignored) 15 bytes [built] [code generated]
./b.png (ignored) 15 bytes [built] [code generated]
./c.gif (ignored) 15 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 68 ms
```

Execute the `dist/main.js`

```
$ node dist/main.js 
webpack mini template
{}
{}
{}
```

If we remove the `ignoreModules`, build and run the `dist/main.js` again:

```
$ node dist/main.js 
webpack mini template
31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c.jpg
a6bcd82b57b58dd91b34.png
31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c.gif
```

Comment: Thanks Lin - that's really helpful! Shame that it wasn't included in the webpack docs when null-loader was deprecated!